# Get variable version number

Tags: bash

I need to extract version number for a version output like the following:

```
    Program updated version 7.9
    Released on 04-04-2013
```

I know how to extract a two-digit version number:

```
   grep -Po '(version )\d+(?:\.\d+){2}')
```

Or any other number of digits.The problem is that the version number may have different number of digits. Is there a regex I can user for a group of several digits separated by dots provided that the number of digits is unknown?

Comment: ``\d[\d\.]*`` – regex for a string starting with a number and containing just digits and points

Comment: @tampis I have just tried your suggestion and i still get only 2 digits. I don't know if i am doing sth wrong. I use version=$(echo $output | grep -Po '\d[\d\.]*').

Comment: Thank you @Jayesh. The colum is not fixed. I have tested your solution and i don't know why but it sorts the numbers in pairs. For example for `"Program updated version 7.9"` the output is `7.9` For `"Program updated version 7.9.9"` the output is still `7.9` and for `"Program updated version 7.9.9.9"` the output is `7.9 9.9` with a space between the pairs

Comment: @fa__ look my answer.

Comment: This worked to me: `grep -Po '(?<=version )[0-9.]+' file` does it suffice or you want other conditions?

Answer (score 1):

With `grep`

```
#!/bin/sh
version=$(echo "Program updated version 7.9.9.9" | grep -oP "(?<=version )[^ ]+")
echo $version
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh
7.9.9.9
```

with `awk`

```
#!/bin/sh
version=$(echo "Program updated version 7.9.9.9" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="version") print $(i+1)}')
echo $version
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh
7.9.9.9
```

Comment: With both this and @fedorqui's suggestion I experience the problem i described above of splitting in pairs.Is it only me with that issue?

Comment: @fa__ if you provide space like `7.9 9.9` then obviously you get `7.9`. i don't understand you what you mean?

Comment: The problem is i don't provide that space. I write `7.9.9.9`.

Comment: @fa__ ok so it display `7.9.9.9` as per my solution.